# JMH - List#addAll faster than ArrayList#new?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, collections, jmh

I have quite a simple JMH Benchmark, I have read left and right that using the constructor of collections should be faster than using the `addAll` method.

However, my benchmark tends to prove the contrary.

Any explanation on that?

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public static class Strings {
    public String string = "String";
    public List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("String123", "String456", "String789");
}

@Benchmark
@Fork(value = 5, warmups = 3)
public List<String> withStreams(Strings input) {
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(input.string), input.strings.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Benchmark
@Fork(value = 5, warmups = 3)
public List<String> withoutStreamsButWithConstructor(Strings input) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(input.strings);
    result.add(input.string);
    return result;
}

@Benchmark
@Fork(value = 5, warmups = 3)
public List<String> withoutStreams(Strings input) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(input.string);
    result.addAll(input.strings);
    return result;
}
```

PS: The example with Streams is just an experiment (in fact the actual things I wanted to be sure of)

Results

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:16:31

Benchmark                              Mode  Cnt         Score        Error  Units
App.withStreams                       thrpt  100  12649053,043 ± 222716,712  ops/s
App.withoutStreams                    thrpt  100  50572729,531 ± 324271,706  ops/s
App.withoutStreamsButWithConstructor  thrpt  100  30179733,201 ± 380273,095  ops/s
```

---

### Update

Added the following benchmark to the family

```
@Benchmark
@Fork(value = 5, warmups = 3)
public List<String> withoutStreamsWithAddAfter(Strings input) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.addAll(input.strings);
    result.add(input.string);
    return result;
}
```

And I now get

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:22:00

Benchmark                              Mode  Cnt         Score        Error  Units
App.withStreams                       thrpt  100  13560464,180 ± 201012,539  ops/s
App.withoutStreams                    thrpt  100  47490197,224 ± 864545,886  ops/s
App.withoutStreamsButWithConstructor  thrpt  100  29412182,733 ± 346228,939  ops/s
App.withoutStreamsWithAddAfter        thrpt  100  31030909,677 ±  81494,995  ops/s
```

So the `withoutStreams` is the most performant one anyway

---

### Update #2

I've tried with the following `List<String>`

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public static class Strings {
    public String string = "String";
    public List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("String123", "String456", "String789", "StringAbc", "StringDef", "StringGhi", "StringJkl", "StringMno", "StringPqr", "StringStu");
}
```

And now the results are indeed better for the constructor `@Benchmark`

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:22:01

Benchmark                              Mode  Cnt         Score        Error  Units
App.withStreams                       thrpt  100   7291967,397 ± 330614,125  ops/s
App.withoutStreams                    thrpt  100  23575768,665 ± 127039,282  ops/s
App.withoutStreamsButWithConstructor  thrpt  100  27046342,511 ± 182227,005  ops/s
App.withoutStreamsWithAddAfter        thrpt  100  17873682,945 ± 170786,259  ops/s
```

Comment: does order matter? adding `string` first or adding `strings` first - should maintain same order in all testes - actually why the single `string`?

Comment: No order does not but I can rerun another one with add after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the reason lies in how ArrayList is implemented.

`withoutStreamsButWithConstructor` creates an array of size 1, and when you call `addAll`, a new array of size 4 is created, the first element is copied over and the other elements are then added.

`withoutStreams` creates an array of size 10 (default capacity) and no resizing is required.

If `strings` contained 10 elements, one array resizing would be required in both methods and I suspect the results would be closer.

More generally, if performance is important, sizing the list correctly with the constructor that takes an `int` can make a difference.

Comment: Thanks @assylias I'll try that right away with 10 elements in `strings`

Comment: Note that this doesn’t disprove the saying that using the constructor is faster than addAll, as the benchmark is not comparing a constructor with addAll. It’s comparing “default constructor, add, addAll” with “copy constructor, add”, for a fixed input size and Java version.